# How to ensure only 1 request for appointment get book if only 1 seat available in Appointment managment

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have done lot of research to get appointment work, but failed to achieve it.

My problem is that I want to ensure appointment booked through system never get exceed from available quota. There is 1 seat available for booking and more than 1 request came to avail that, I need to be sure that only one request which is came first get booked and rest will receive error message that "no seat available.".

I have tried several ways to achieve:

- I put synchronized block
- lock and unlock
- static resource

etc. but none of them worked for me.

I am using Spring Boot 1.5.3 with Thymeleaf.

Comment: Post soem of your sever side code that isn't working and clarfify exactly what happens

Comment: Please check this https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-pessimistic-locking. Pessimistic Locking can be a solution to your problem.